# how to refresh a function on next.js to update a table?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, components, refresh

I have a simple page that has a table and a button
the button open a modal with a form to insert data into the database by API URL and on this page, there is a table that shows what is inside of database, but still learning and when i use the modal, the query works but the table don't update How do I make the table update when the process of the modal finishes?

This is the table component:

```
//"use client";
//import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

/* ------------------------------ Buscar dados ------------------------------ */
async function getSurveys() {
  const APIURL = process.env.API_URL;
  const res = await fetch(`${APIURL}/api/surveys`, {
    method: "GET",
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  return res.json();
}

export async function TableSurveys() {
  const surveysData: any[] = await getSurveys();
  const surveys = Array.from(surveysData);

  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Nome</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {surveys.map((survey) => (
          <tr key={survey.id}>
            <td className="align-middle">{survey.name}</td>
            <td className="text-end">
              <Link
                href={`/avaliacao/${survey.id}`}
                className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary me-2"
              >
                Entrar
              </Link>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-sm btn-light part_del"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#modal_excluir"
                data-aval-id={survey.id}
              >
                <span className="btn-label">
                  <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

This is the button-modal component:

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import { FormEvent } from "react";

/* ------------------------------- components ------------------------------- */
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

/* -------------------------- renderizar componente ------------------------- */
export function ModalNewSurvey() {
  const [modalNewAval, setModalNewAval] = useState(false);
  const [nomeAvaliacao, setNomeAvaliacao] = useState("");

  const handleShow = () => setModalNewAval(true);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setNomeAvaliacao(""); // Clear the input field
    setModalNewAval(false);
  };

  // adicionar survey
  async function onSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault(); // nao submita o form
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget); // pega os dados
    handleClose(); // fecha o modal

    // Gera um ID usando a função uuidv4()
    const id = v4();

    // Adiciona o ID ao formulário
    formData.append("id", id);

    // Converte os dados em JSON
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      id: formData.get("id"),
      name: formData.get("name"),
    });
    //console.log(data);

    const APIURL = process.env.API_URL; // pega url
    const response = await fetch(`/api/surveys`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    //console.log(formData);

    // Handle response if necessary
    //const data = await response.json();
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleShow} className="me-2">
        <span className="btn-label">
          <i className="fa fa-plus me-2"></i>
        </span>
        Criar Avaliação
      </Button>

      <Modal
        show={modalNewAval}
        onHide={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-sm"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-sm">
            Criar Avaliação
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="NomeAvaliacao">
              <Form.Label>Nome da Avaliação</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="ex: Setor Administrativo 1"
                value={nomeAvaliacao}
                name="name"
                onChange={(e) => setNomeAvaliacao(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Cancelar
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit">Criar Avaliação</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is the page:

```
/* -------------------------------- metadata -------------------------------- */
import { Metadata } from "next";
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Avaliações",
};

/* ------------------------------- components ------------------------------- */
import { ModalNewSurvey } from "@/app/comps/modal_new_survey";
import { TableSurveys } from "@/app/comps/table_surveys";

/* ---------------------------- renderizar pagina --------------------------- */
export default async function SurveysPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mt-4">
        <div className="container mt-3 mt-sm-5 mb-3">
          <div className="row ">
            <div className="col-md">
              <h2>Avaliações</h2>
              <p>Crie avaliações e seus grupos de participantes.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-auto text-md-end text-end d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
              <ModalNewSurvey />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <TableSurveys />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Some simple solution maybe or smart solution
I am on next.js the lastest with server components rules :/